# Scapy PcapReader Memory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, pcap, scapy

I have a proble with scapy's PcapReader, which causes MemoryError (with no description) when many packets are read.

I've created my own reader by extending PcapReader and I re-write scapy's `read_all` method so it returns `generator` instead of loading it all to a list.

```
class MyPcapReader(PcapReader):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        PcapReader.__init__(self, filename)


    def read_all(self,count=-1):
        """return an iterable of all packets in the pcap file
        """
        while count != 0:
            count -= 1
            p = self.read_packet()
            if p is None:
                break

            yield p
```

Here's how I retrive data

```
reader = MyPcapReader(fname).read_all()

for p in reader:

    processSingle(p)
```

Where can be the problem? When I switch back to the implementation with list, exception is raised within read_all. With generator it raises in for loop. So problem is in loop iteration, but I don't understand, where is problem with generator.

Comment: How big is the PCAP you are reading?

Answer (score 0):

You redefine read_all(). I don't think that you should do that

Comment: Well, implementation of PcapReader causes the same error. I don't want to rewrite its implementation in source file and I've think there shouldn't be problems with inheritation of the class

Comment: Can you run like wireshark properly?

Comment: Okay, it seems the file is corrupted. Anyway, getting "MemoryError" is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `.read_all()` method is exactly that: read all the packets at once and return them in a list (technically, a `PacketList` instance, but that has the same effect on memory usage). If your PCAP file is to big, you seem to get a `MemoryError`, which sounds OK to me.

If you don't want a list but rather a generator (which is indeed a good choice, especially when dealing with huge PCAP files), you can iterate over the `PcapReader()` object directly, there's no need to create your own subclass:

```
for p in PcapReader(fname):
    processSingle(p)
```